# MongoDB: Searching for multiple strings in a field through C# client

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on MongoDB and C# client.
I am having the following data in collection:

```
 1- { _id: xId, Desc: "ABC BLX CPO"}
 2- { _id: yId, Desc: "ZNP CKL IOP ERKK"}
 3- { _id: zId, Desc: "POL MIU WER XDF RRF"}
```

Now the issue is I have to search for dynamic values in Desc field depending upon user requirements. e.g 
Searching for one string "ABC" at time, 
Next time may be I have to search for two strings in Desc field "XYZ" and "IOP"
Next time may be I have search for five strings

I create a list of these search keywords(whether it is one, two or any number) and loop it through and search one by one :

```
list = ["ABC", "XYZ", "IOP"];
foreach(string item in list)
{
      findInDB(item);
}

void findInDB(string val)
{
       db.Collection.find({"Desc" : /val /i}) //pseudo code
}
```

Although the above code is working for me, but it takes too much time as I have a very rich database.

I am looking for some efficient way to achieve the goal. kindly guide me if there is any possibility.

Comment: You should consider a Text index :https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html